# Why is .NET performance so good?

Tags: .net, performance, runtime

Lately I've been looking at some performance comparisons and .NET programs are consistently highly performant. Sometimes they are faster than native programs written in something like Golang.

[Some algorithm comparisons vs golang](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/go-csharpcore.html)

[One networking example](https://github.com/ixy-languages/ixy-languages)

Why are .NET programs so performant? Is there somewhere I can read about how Microsoft is able to achieve such good results for something that requires a runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [this talk](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/performance-managed-languages/) by Martin Thompson.  Note that as the .NET runtime JIT compiles the native code there are opportunities to generate more efficient code based on runtime heuristics.  Gil Tene has an [intersting talk](https://www.azul.com/presentation/webinar-java-at-speed/) on this topic which is Java oriented but the same principles apply.

For .NET specific things I would look at the recent performance improvements in the runtime listed here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/author/toub/

Also, there is lots of information posted on Twitter by @davidfowl, @ben_a_adams and others.